# How can I get page content inside an iframe as string in javascript? I want everything from <html> to </html>

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, innerhtml

I want to get content from an page that loaded in an `iframe`, edit that content using DOM manipulation and export edited content into a new page. But I can't get content from iframe as string so I cannot export it into a new file.

Follows a code extraction:

```
const innerFrame = clientWindow.contentDocument || clientWindow.contentWindow.document;
//Other code
//...
//...
exportFile('new-file.html', innerFrame.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me :

```
document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```